# How to write Docker file and compose.yml in .NET project if it contains tailwind.css

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core-mvc, tailwind-css, asp.net-core-8

I'm trying to setup ASP.NET Core 8 MVC project for my CRUD application. The Docker compose works fine out of the box with `docker init`. However, when I try to add tailwind.css for my frontend part Docker throw an error on server image. It's trying to read the config from `.csproj` file which make sense as the error is

> Error MSB3073: The command "npm run css:build" exited with code 127

I assume that the my DockerFile or even `compose.yml` have nothing to do with `node.js`.

My question is in my case, what is the way to go for running Docker in this case?

Do I need separate frontend image and server image? Which means do I need separate DockerFile, one for node.js and one for .NET?

compose.yml

```
services:
  server:
    build:
      context: .
      target: development
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    depends_on:
       db:
         condition: service_healthy
    develop:
        watch:
        - action: rebuild
          path: .
    environment:
       - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
       - ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:80'
  db:
     image: postgres
     restart: always
     user: postgres
     secrets:
       - db-password
     volumes:
       - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
     environment:
       - POSTGRES_DB=example
       - POSTGRES_PASSWORD_FILE=/run/secrets/db-password
     expose:
       - 5432
     healthcheck:
       test: [ "CMD", "pg_isready" ]
       interval: 10s
       timeout: 5s
       retries: 5
volumes:
 db-data:
secrets:
   db-password:
     file: db/password.txt
```

DockerFile

```
FROM --platform=$BUILDPLATFORM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0-alpine AS build
ARG TARGETARCH
COPY . /source
WORKDIR /source
RUN --mount=type=cache,id=nuget,target=/root/.nuget/packages \
    dotnet publish -a ${TARGETARCH/amd64/x64} --use-current-runtime --self-contained false -o /app

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0-alpine AS development
COPY . /source
WORKDIR /source
CMD dotnet run --no-launch-profile

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0-alpine AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app .
USER $APP_UID
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "myCoffeeScript.dll"]
```

.csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <UpToDateCheckBuilt Include="wwwroot/css/site.css" Set="Css" />
    <UpToDateCheckBuilt Include="tailwind.config.js" Set="Css" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <Target Name="Tailwind" BeforeTargets="Build">
    <Exec Command="npm run css:build"/>
  </Target>
</Project>
```

The last two group is one that got added when installed tailwind. which is the one that throw an error (`<Exec Command="npm run css:build"/>`)

The expected outcome of my problem is I can run Docker containers for ASP.NET Core 8 MVC app which include one image for DB, one for server and maybe another one for frontend?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install node and npm in the build step image. You can do this using the Alpine package manager with the command `apk add nodejs npm`. Try this

```
FROM --platform=$BUILDPLATFORM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0-alpine AS build
ARG TARGETARCH
RUN apk add nodejs npm
COPY . /source
WORKDIR /source
RUN --mount=type=cache,id=nuget,target=/root/.nuget/packages \
    dotnet publish -a ${TARGETARCH/amd64/x64} --use-current-runtime --self-contained false -o /app

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0-alpine AS development
COPY . /source
WORKDIR /source
CMD dotnet run --no-launch-profile

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0-alpine AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app .
USER $APP_UID
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "myCoffeeScript.dll"]
```